# Convergence of the series such that $|a_{k}-a_{l}|>1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Given the sequence $(a_{n})$ such that for all $k,l$ we have $|a_{k}-a_{l}|>1$. Prove that for all, $x \notin (a_{n})$ series $\sum \frac{1}{(x-a_{n})^{2}} $  converges.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: since $|x-a_l - (x-a_k)| = |a_l-a_k|,$ you can forget about $x$ and only consider $\sum\frac{1}{a_n^2}$

Comment: and if you imagine to permute your sequence in an increasing order, then you can get convergence by comparison with $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$. But this is also an absolute convergence, which means that any permutation is also convergent to begin with.